# How can I share a ContextMenu between Components

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a WPF application that uses the same Menu component in many places.  Because of this, I'd like my menu to be a separate component that I somehow invoke where it's needed.  As of now, my Menu view logic looks like so.

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding MenuDelegateCommand}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OpenEnabled}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Blah Attributes">
        <MenuItem Header="Properties" Command="{Binding MenuDelegateCommand}"
                                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OpenEnabled}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" />
......
```

Thus far, I've tried breaking out the the ContextMenu part into its own class like so

```
<UserControl>
 <Grid>
   <ContextMenu>
```

but a ContextMenu interacts with the Visual Tree differently, so that is a no-go.  I've thought of other things, but between Templates, DataTemplates and Adorners I am lost.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for static resources.  Make your ContextMenu a resource inside of a top-level element (or in a separate resources file and then including the ResourceDictionary):

```xml
<!-- Use whatever control you want here, or a separate resources
     file if you want to share across controls                   -->
<Window.Resources>
  <ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding MenuDelegateCommand}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OpenEnabled}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Blah Attributes">
        <MenuItem Header="Properties" Command="{Binding MenuDelegateCommand}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OpenEnabled}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" />
  </ContextMenu>
......
</Window.Resources>
```

And then refer to the context menu later on:

```
<TreeView ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}" />
```

Comment: Thanks MackieChan I'll have to try this tomorrow.  One question though,  will the whole PlacementTarget hocus-pocus used to get the DataContext into the ContextMenu still work?